# Quantile instrumental variable models (Chernozhukov and Hansen)

Tags: regression, stata, instrumental-variables, quantile-regression

I am trying to implement a quantile IV model, and I must confess that I'm not fully familiar (read: comfortable) with the theory, although I have read the Chernozhukov and Hansen paper. However, the CQIV do code in Stata only provides confidence interval, and no standard errors. Why is this? 
Is the model such that it is not possible to get standard errors? Surely bootstrap would work, since that is how we get the confidence intervals?

Reference: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304407605000643
Chernozhukov, Victor, and Christian Hansen. "Instrumental quantile regression inference for structural and treatment effect models." Journal of Econometrics 132.2 (2006): 491-525.

Comment: NB: there are three different approaches to QR with endogeneity, with three different sets of assumptions. None is "better" or "worse," just appropriate for different applications. See Section 1.2.5 in https://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/christian.hansen/research/IVQRchapter-latestversion_v4.pdf for more (published version: Section 9.2.5 in Chapter 9 in the Handbook of Quantile Regression). I think Stata's cqiv is actually the control function approach, not the "instrumental variables" approach of Chernozhukov and Hansen (2005,2006).

Answer (score 1):

For Stata estimation of the [Chernozhukov and Hansen (2005)](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1468-0262.2005.00570.x) IVQR model, within Stata issue command

```
net from https://kaplandm.github.io/stata
```

and follow instructions to install the sivqr command.

The cqiv command is actually based on a different underlying model (a triangular system).

For details on all of this, see the Stata Journal article draft (in 3rd round of review as of 24feb2022) at https://kaplandm.github.io/#sivqr